# Adding Image to Wrappanel by code

Tags: c#, wpf, image, wrappanel

I've got a a Wrappanel in my WPF like:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="dockpnlCollection_Covers" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" LastChildFill="False" Margin="0" >
            <WrapPanel x:Name="wpnlCollection_Covers" Orientation="Vertical" MinWidth="520" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}, Path=ActualWidth}"></WrapPanel>
        </DockPanel>
```

My c#-Code looks like:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= nmbr; x++)
            {
                cmddb.CommandText = "SELECT cover FROM movies Where nr = '" + x + "'";
                dbreader.Read();
                while (dbreader.Read())
                {
                    coverpath = (string)dbreader["cover"];
                    System.Windows.Controls.Image newIMG = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
                    newIMG.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness { Left = 6, Top = 5, Right = 6, Bottom = 5 };
                    newIMG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(coverpath));
                    wpnlCollection_Covers.Children.Add(newIMG);
                }
            }

            dbreader.Close();
```

I don't get any errors while compiling but my wrappanel stays blank and I can't figure out why.

I'm using nearly the same code on another page to generate Checkbox-Controls and it works just fine.

Could anyone please give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to remove the binding in the Width property) (sometimes it's happened to me that the control was actually collapsed and this was the reason why it was impossible to see the controls inside) Why aren't you using a ViewModel approach (with an ItemsControl, for example) to do this?

Comment: Are you sure that the column "nr" is a varchar and not a number?

Comment: your coverpath string does not contain the entire file name, it lacks the extension, look in solution explorer for the complete File Name path of your image.

Comment: @bastio84: Removing the binding didnt help. I'll have a look at the ItemsControl and see if I understand it ;-)

Comment: @CiccioRocca: no it's not a varchar it acctually is a number. Is there something wrong with my SQL Command?

Comment: @DarkTemplar: The string inside my database contains the file ending (.jpg)

Comment: @mykds i added a solution. You are inserting ' character. This is not correct when you are referring to a column that is a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If column **nr** is a number this should fix your query:

```
cmddb.CommandText = "SELECT cover FROM movies Where nr = " + x.ToString();
```

You are treating it as a string and not as a number (you are using ' character into your query).

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that your initial `Read()` should be deleted

```
        cmddb.CommandText = "SELECT cover FROM movies Where nr = '" + x + "'";
        //dbreader.Read(); // is it wrong, maybe?
        while (dbreader.Read())
```